# Embedding Groovy in Java (Binding)

Tags: java, binding, groovy, embedding

I try to Bind Variables to Groovy and from Groovy back zu Java:

Java code:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("SRESULT", "foo");
GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell(binding);
gs.evaluate(script);
String sResult = (String) gs.getContext().getVariable("SRESULT");
System.out.println("FROM GROOVY: " + sResult);
```

Groovy Code:

```
class Est {  
  static SRESULT
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    println 'From Java: '+SRESULT
    SRESULT = 'bar'
  }
}
```

Output:

```
From Java: foo
FROM GROOVY: foo
```

My Question: I want to change `SRESULT` in Groovy and have access to the Value in Java.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 8):

The binding only applies to *scripts*, not to *classes*.  If your Groovy code were a script, i.e. just the content of the `main` method without the surrounding class body

```
println 'From Java: '+SRESULT
SRESULT = 'bar'
```

then it would produce the result you expect.  In particular you must not *declare* the `SRESULT` variable in the script, i.e.

```
def SRESULT = 'bar'
```

would *not* work.  This is because the declarations (with `def` or with an explicit type) create local variables within the script, they do not assign to the binding.

Comment: @user1734715 if the answer worked for you you should consider _accepting_ it by clicking the tick mark to the left.  Building a track record of accepting good answers is the best way to encourage people to help you with future questions.

Answer (score 4):

Given `Test.java` containing:

```
import groovy.lang.Binding ;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell ;
import java.io.File ;

public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Binding binding = new Binding() ;
        binding.setVariable( "SRESULT", "foo" ) ;

        GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell( binding ) ;
        gs.evaluate( new File( "script.groovy" ) ) ;

        String sResult = (String)binding.getVariable( "SRESULT" ) ;
        System.out.printf( "FROM GROOVY: %s\n", sResult ) ;
    }
}
```

And `script.groovy` containing:

```
println "From Java: $SRESULT"
SRESULT = 'bar'
```

We can compile `Test.java` by doing:

```
javac -cp $GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.1.jar:. Test.java
```

And then running it with:

```
java -cp $GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.1.jar:. Test
```

Gives the output:

```
From Java: foo
FROM GROOVY: bar
```

Comment: 2023-01-01: There is no `$GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-###.jar` anymore, but `$GROOVY_HOME/lib/groovy-###.jar` can be used instead.